# Can't read form data of http post request in java

Tags: java, http, post, httprequest

The program just read form head and stops.

```
//...

Socket client = server.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

System.out.println("Request:");

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    if (line.length() > 0)
    System.out.println("\t" + line);
        else break;

in.close();
client.close();
```

When I try to submit some form on browser:

```
Waiting for request...
Connection accepted.
Request:
    POST /form.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: x-x-x-x
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 31
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Origin: http://neviat.us.to
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Referer: http://x-x-x-x
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection closed.
```

I got the `Content-Length`, but nothing about the content itself. ¬¬
I thougth that could be the `else break;`, so I took it off and tried again:

```
Waiting for request...
Connection accepted.
Request:
    POST /buy.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: x-x-x-x
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 31
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Origin: http://neviat.us.to
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Referer: http://x-x-x-x
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

    // stop here, waiting for stream...
```

But the content isn't there too.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (line.length() > 0)
```

to

```
if (line.length() > -1)
```

lines of 0 length are perfectly valid

Comment: But even if I did not check it and print all I get, the content is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

**Change In code:**

//...

```
Socket client = server.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

System.out.println("Request:");

while ((line = in.readLine()) != -1)
    if (line.length() > 0)
    System.out.println("\t" + line);
        else break;

in.close();
client.close();
```